# Add custom SQL column in register

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

environment: vs2017, .core net 2.1, default .core project with MVC

I try to add `NickName` column store in SQL DB, i had update DB and also add `NickName` column in the input model. it succeeds to show input the NickName option in the register page but fault to write into SQL DB after clicks register(and other work as usual).

after override IdentityUser it does not work.

add/chg code in Register.cshtml.cs:

```
        public class CustomUserproperties : IdentityUser
        {
            public string NickName { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //here is where i change.
                var user = new CustomUserproperties { UserName = Input.UserName, Email = Input.Email, NickName = Input.NickName };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

what could i do else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo, you could refer to create a new or check the difference between your old one.

1.Modify ApplicationDbContext and Add-migration , update-database

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomUserproperties>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

2. Scaffold the Identity with the above ApplicationDbContext , then you could get RegisterModel like below:

```
 public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<CustomUserproperties> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<CustomUserproperties> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<CustomUserproperties> userManager,
        SignInManager<CustomUserproperties> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "NickName")]
        public string NickName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new CustomUserproperties { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email , NickName = Input.NickName };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

3.Change the ConfigureServices in StartUp.cs

```
     services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
     services.AddDefaultIdentity<CustomUserproperties>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

4._LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@inject SignInManager<CustomUserproperties> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<CustomUserproperties> UserManager
```

Here is my [project](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/Ee-Xlbl6Nl1ImStWnZ9spFQB2JX21Eu1B2Uwjx6-bECG5A?e=PoZRG9) .